# How to extract strings from a list in a column in a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a list

```
lst = ["fi", "ap", "ko", "co", "ex"]
```

and we have this series

```
       Explanation 

a      "fi doesn't work correctly" 
b      "apples are cool" 
c      "this works but translation is ko"
```

and I'm looking to get something like this:

```
        Explanation                         Explanation Extracted

a      "fi doesn't work correctly"          "fi"
b      "apples are cool"                    "N/A"
c      "this works but translation is ko"   "ko"
```

Comment: What would be the return for `"fi ex"`?

Answer (score 1):

With a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Explanation": ["fi doesn't co work correctly",
                     "apples are cool",
                     "this works but translation is ko"]},
    index=["a", "b", "c"]
)
```

you can use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to do

```
lst = ["fi", "ap", "ko", "co", "ex"]

pattern = r"(?:^|\s+)(" + "|".join(lst) + r")(?:\s+|$)"
df["Explanation Extracted"] = df.Explanation.str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
```

to get

```
                        Explanation Explanation Extracted
a      fi doesn't co work correctly                    fi
b                   apples are cool                   NaN
c  this works but translation is ko                    ko
```

The regex pattern `r"(?:^|\s+)(" + "|".join(lst) + r")(?:\s+|$)"` looks for an occurrence of one of the `lst` items either at the beginning with withespace afterwards, in the middle with whitespace before and after, or at the end with withespace before. `str.extract()` *extracts* the capture group (the part in the middle in `()`). Without a match the return is `NaN`.

If you want to extract multiple matches, you could use [`.str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and then `", ".join` the results:

```
pattern = r"(?:^|\s+)(" + "|".join(lst) + r")(?:\s+|$)"
df["Explanation Extracted"] = (
    df.Explanation.str.findall(pattern).str.join(", ").replace({"": None})
)
```

---

Alternative without regex:

```
df.index = df.index.astype("category")
matches = df.Explanation.str.split().explode().loc[lambda s: s.isin(lst)]
df["Explanation Extracted"] = (
    matches.groupby(level=0).agg(set).str.join(", ").replace({"": None})
)
```

If you only want to match at the beginning or end of the sentences, then replace the first part with:

```
df.index = df.index.astype("category")
splitted = df.Explanation.str.split()
matches = (
    (splitted.str[:1] + splitted.str[-1:]).explode().loc[lambda s: s.isin(lst)]
)
...
```

Comment: Always best to `re.escape` here just in case. And... sort by descending length of the search strings so the most complete match comes first in case of overlaps.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks! The items in the list didn't look like they need escaping, but you are right. Regarding the sorting: I don't think it matters here, since the parts are embedded in string-beginning/end and whitespace (I've run some tests and they seem to confirm my reasoning)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ["fi", "ap", "ko", "co", "ex"]
df = pd.DataFrame([["fi doesn't work correctly"],["apples are cool"],["this works but translation is ko"]],columns=["Explanation"])

extracted =[] 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tempList =[] 
    rowSplit = row['Explanation'].split(" ")
    for val in rowSplit:
        if val in lst:
            tempList.append(val)
    if len(tempList)>0:
        extracted.append(','.join(tempList))
    else:
        extracted.append('N/A')

df['Explanation Extracted'] = extracted
```

Answer (score 0):

[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function of Pandas might be helpful

```
def extract_explanation(dataframe):
    custom_substring = ["fi", "ap", "ko", "co", "ex"]
    substrings = dataframe['explanation'].split(" ")
    explanation = "N/A"
    for string in substrings:
        if string in custom_substring:
            explanation = string
    return explanation

df['Explanation Extracted'] = df.apply(extract_explanation, axis=1)
```

The catch here is assumption of only one explanation, but it can be converted into a list, if multiple explanations are expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Assuming that one wants to extract the exact string in the list `lst` one can start by creating a regex

```
regex = f'\\b({"|".join(lst)})\\b'
```

where `\b` is the word boundary (beginning or end of a word) that indicates the word is not followed by additional characters, or with characters before. So, considering that one has the string `ap` in the list `lst`, if one has the word `apple` in the dataframe, that won't be considered.

And then, using [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), and, to make it case insensitive, use [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE)

```
import re

df['Explanation Extracted'] = df['Explanation'].str.extract(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)

[Out]:
   ID                       Explanation Explanation Extracted
0   1         fi doesn't work correctly                    fi
1   2                 cap ples are cool                   NaN
2   3  this works but translation is ko                    ko
```

---

**Option 2**

One can also use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom lambda function.

```
df['Explanation Extracted'] = df['Explanation'].apply(lambda x: next((i for i in lst if i.lower() in x.lower().split()), 'N/A'))

[Out]:
   ID                       Explanation Explanation Extracted
0   1         fi doesn't work correctly                    fi
1   2                 cap ples are cool                   N/A
2   3  this works but translation is ko                    ko
```

**Notes:**

- `.lower()` is to make it case insensitive.
- `.split()` is one way to prevent that even though `ap` is in the list, the string `apple` doesn't appear in the `Explanation Extracted` column.